Can any software directly run a t-test on lognormal data
If your data are sampled from lognormal distributions, running a t-test requires:

Transforming all values to logarithms.
Running a t-test on the logarithms. The p-value tests the null hypothesis that both data sets are sampled from identical lognormal distributions.
Reverse transforming (antilog) the difference between means (log scale) and the confidence limits. The result is the ratio of geometric means and the confidence interval for that ratio.

It is easy enough to do steps 1 and 3 manually, and use any stats program to run the t-test (step 2). And I suppose it would be easy enough to write a R script that does all those steps. My question is if there are any statistical software that does this lognormal t-test (all three steps).
